# How to fix Kucoin 400 Bad Request - APIs - Python

Tags: python, api, kucoin

**I wanted to place order limit with my kucoin api using python but all i got is (Bad Request) 400. How do I solve this, please I need help.
here is my code.**

```
stringId  = secrets.token_hex(8) #Generating TradeID
url = 'https://api.kucoin.com/api/v1/orders'
now = int(time.time() * 1000)
str_to_sign = str(now) + 'POST' + '/api/v1/orders'
signature = base64.b64encode(
    hmac.new(api_secret.encode('utf-8'), str_to_sign.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest())
passphrase = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(api_secret.encode('utf-8'), api_passphrase.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest())
headers = {
    "KC-API-SIGN": signature,
    "KC-API-TIMESTAMP": str(now),
    "KC-API-KEY": api_key,
    "KC-API-PASSPHRASE": passphrase,
    "KC-API-KEY-VERSION": "2",
    "clientOid": stringId,
    "side": "sell",
    "symbol": "AFK-USDT",
    "type": "limit",
    "price": "0.05",
    "size": "50.00",
    
}
response = requests.request('post', url, headers=headers)
print(response.status_code)
print(response.json())
```

***This is the error response I got back***

```
400
{'code': '400000', 'msg': 'Bad Request'}
```

Comment: The parameters like `clientOid`, `symbol`, etc. are most likely NOT to be sent as header, but in the body of the POST request. Any reason, why you do not use the _python-kucoin-sdk_?

Comment: Please can you give me an example 
@M.Spiller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a python module called [kucoin-python-sdk](https://github.com/Kucoin/kucoin-python-sdk) that does all this for you.

If you would use this library it would boil down to one line like

```
client.create_limit_order('AFK-USDT', 'sell', '50', '0.05')
```

---

If you cannot use this module, you have to follow KuCoin's documentation:

According to KuCoin's documentation, parameters have to be sent in the body of the POST request, not as headers.

So your code should be similar to this:

```
params = {
    "clientOid": stringId,
    "side": "sell",
    "symbol": "AFK-USDT",
    "type": "limit",
    "price": "0.05",
    "size": "50.00"
}

data_json = json.dumps(params)

str_to_sign = str(now) + 'POST' + '/api/v1/orders' + data_json
signature = base64.b64encode(
    hmac.new(api_secret.encode('utf-8'), str_to_sign.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest())
passphrase = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(api_secret.encode('utf-8'), api_passphrase.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest())
headers = {
    "KC-API-SIGN": signature,
    "KC-API-TIMESTAMP": str(now),
    "KC-API-KEY": api_key,
    "KC-API-PASSPHRASE": passphrase,
    "KC-API-KEY-VERSION": "2",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

response = requests.request('post', url, headers=headers, data=data_json)
```

Comment: Am still having issue with the response, 415
{'code': '415000', 'msg': 'Unsupported Media Type'} @M. Spiller

Comment: Most likely a `Content-Type` Header was missing. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Can I get ur contact? @M. Spiller